# Move a Text box in a PDF viewer using PDFKIT - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit, pdf-viewer

I am working on this project https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/BookReader to expand it. It is a PDF viewer implemented by PDFKIT and everything works fine there. but I have a problem in moving an element on the PDF file. I am very new to swift so I really appreciate if some one could help me any how . 
I created a text box like the image below in my story board.
[image]

and in the result when I run the app is like this

[image]

you see it works fine in PDFViewr too. now my problem is that I want to find a way to move this yellow text box during the page by touching it (and also change the height and width of it ). once before , I have found a way using `GestureRecognizer` but it does not work more after iOS 13. I searched a lot but I all my efforts failed because non of the solutions worked for my project. I really appreciate if help me and even if payment needed, Its very important for me

Thank you very very much

Comment: Are you using a `PDFAnnotation` object for the sticky note?

Comment: yes but I have some  conflicts with my other parts of my code , can you help me? @ShunzheM

Comment: Can you share me the link to the part of your code that moves the position of the annotation so I can take a better look into the issue?

Comment: you know its very complicated project. and I really do not know where is the exact problem. If you are ready to help, then I think we could chat together? I can appreciate any how you prefer.